# Laminate floor sliding out of place

Tags: repair, laminate-floor

I learned the hard way not to plank on floating laminate floor when the board my feet were on slid toward the wall.

I fixed it initially by just applying force in the other direction, but now it keeps on slipping out and I keep on slipping it back. It doesn't take much to move it anymore.

Can I fix it with wood glue or something stronger? It slides a good half an inch so there's plenty of space to gunk stuff in there. Otherwise, it is pretty close to the edge of the trim so I could pull that back and try wedging something in to stop it from moving.

[image: gap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happened is that you broke off the MDF tab that was holding that plank in place. That's why it slides freely now; nothing's mechanically holding it in place anymore. Since the core is MDF, any kind of wood glue should be totally fine to fuse them together, and once glued, those two planks will probably be more strongly held to one another than the other ones that are only mechanically fastened. Once you apply the glue, tape the planks together with masking tape or blue painter's tape to prevent the glue from expanding and pushing them apart.

If you *really* wanna make sure it never comes loose again, you can get some of the wood wood glue that's specifically made for this use: Titebond!

[image]

Comment: You should use a flooring glue not just any wood glue. Flooring glue is designed to remain flexible  so it will not crack and fail do to flexing from the weight of walking on it.

Comment: This *is* floating floor glue. It is specifically recommended by the manufacturers of many engineered floor boards. Of course, check first as manufacturers may have different recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I use a flooring glue also.  Mine would not slide easily and were in the middle of the floor.  I used a tool from another post.  It is the "Floor Gap Fixer".  Found it @floorgapfixer.com.  My problem was that it wasn't only one spot and they returned in different spots after they were glued.