# How do I Clean and Seal Laminate floors?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, laminate-floor

My home has laminate (but appears wood) floors, and I want to emulate what we did in the Military, but I don't know any of the product names (just the slang, Sealer)

I have use Linseed Oil on hardwood floors in the past, and really liked the what I got out of it.

Can I use Linseed Oil on my floor to the same effect, or is there a better product to help protect my floors? (Side note: I don't care about the floors look, I care about keeping the material from becoming damaged)

Also, given the suggested protectant: What would be the best way to clean those now-sealed floors?

Answer (score 1):

Laminate flooring is not made to be sealed after installation.  The floors are made with a protective coating that make them durable.  Typically they have a good warranty on them.  The only problem I had was gaps.  My floor was not level and when the seasons changed I would get gaps.  I finally solved that from [another post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/100199/35141) on the site.

Comment: This one? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/41528/laminate-floor-sliding-out-of-place/100752#100752

Comment: Yeah, most of these floors have a surface impregnated with aluminum oxide, which is nearly as hard as diamond. They're not intended to be waxed, polished, or sealed.

Comment: This one.  http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/58532/60725  I'm not sure if I added this correctly.  Dylan's post was the one.  I saw it after the HOD didn't work.